# Trying to return the number of records to the console that I've inserted?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert into a staging table all data that meet a specific criteria. In this example it is for any entries where the last_updated date comes later than the max_modified_date of a table. This piece works for me; however, I added a degree of complexity by accepting an IN parameter (any random number) and an OUT parameter (a number that is calculated by adding the 'Random Number' from the IN parameter to the number of entries that were inserted. This number is represented by the rUpdated_Row_Count_2 variable in my code. When I run the code, the only value being printed to my console right now is '0'. My code is below:

```
create or replace procedure test_proc(rUpdated_Row_Count IN NUMBER, rUpdated_ROW_COUNT_2 OUT NUMBER)
is
   max_modified_date date;
BEGIN
    select max(modify_dt) into max_modified_date from value;

    for  rec_ in (
                  select value_id, modify_dt as last_update
                from value
              ) loop
                    if rec_.last_update > max_modified_date THEN
                        insert into table2_test( table2_id, last_update )
                                    values( null, rec_.last_update);
                                  rUpdated_Row_Count_2 := rUpdated_Row_Count_2 + 1;
                          end if;
                    end loop;
            end;
/



DECLARE
  rUpdated_Row_Count number;
  rUpdated_Row_Count_2 number := 1;
BEGIN
--    dbms_output.put_line(rUpdated_Row_Count || rUpdated_Row_Count_2);
    test_proc(1, rUpdated_Row_Count_2);
    dbms_output.put_line(rUpdated_Row_Count || rUpdated_Row_Count_2); 
END;
/
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Is your DBMS_OUTPUT returns NULL?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i edited my question, sorry.

Comment: @KKK I am returning 0 and then blank for the two variables respectively.

Comment: I have posted answer in detail, did you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle returns NULL if your add any integer with NULL values, and in your code rUpdated_ROW_COUNT_2 is NULL for procedure, because the value "1" that you are passing while caling will not accept due to OUT parameter. Or else, you have to make "rUpdated_ROW_COUNT_2 OUT NUMBER" to "rUpdated_ROW_COUNT_2 IN OUT NUMBER"
Your procedure code should be:

```
create or replace procedure test_proc(rUpdated_Row_Count IN NUMBER, rUpdated_ROW_COUNT_2 OUT NUMBER)
is
   max_modified_date date;
   v_1 number := 0;
BEGIN
    select max(modify_dt) into max_modified_date from value;

    for  rec_ in (
                  select value_id, modify_dt as last_update
                from value
              ) loop
                    if rec_.last_update > max_modified_date THEN
                        insert into table2_test( table2_id, last_update )
                                    values( null, rec_.last_update);
                                  v_1 := v_1 + 1;
                          end if;
                    end loop;
rUpdated_Row_Count_2 := v_1;
            end;
```

Comment: i am returning 1. I am guessing it is not looping? when i check the table all of the inserts seem to have happened but the counter only went up by 1.

Comment: I have pointed out your mistake here, I think you have to update your question with table structure that are used in Code. with specifying the keys also

Comment: thank you, sorry about that. i've marked your answer as the best one. really appreciate the help

Comment: @John - You should probably declared a cursor and used cursor attribute as I suggested in your duplicate post. Declare CURSOR your cur IS SELECT....FROM... WHERE.... BEGIN... FOR some_rec IN your_cur LOOP your_cur%ROWCOUNT - fetch this into some variable inside the loop. Display the value of this variable after loop - this will display the total records processed. Done!!!! General rules to follow. If you need return a value you create function. If you need process records you do this in procedure. Get the Stven Fuerstain PL/SQL book and watch his videos. This is one of the best authors....

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example to illustrate my comment. Test it in Scott schema:

```
DECLARE
 PROCEDURE process_recs (p_dept_no scott.dept.deptno%TYPE)
 IS
  CURSOR e_cur IS
  SELECT empno, ename
    FROM scott.emp
   WHERE deptno = p_dept_no;

   v_recs_processed NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  FOR e_rec IN e_cur LOOP
    v_recs_processed:= e_cur%ROWCOUNT;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_recs_processed);
END;
BEGIN
  process_recs(10);
END;
/
```

Output:

```
 3
```